# javax.servlet.Filter - ClassCastExeption

Tags: java, java-ee, filter

При написании фильтров для веб сервиса и загрузке Tomcat я получаю ошибку.

Кто сможет объяснить что происходит при загрузке сервера и почему он преобразует в Filter?

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/register"}, filterName = "regRequestFilter")
public class RegisterRequestFilter implements RequestFilter{


@Override
@Context
public void RequestFiltering(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}

@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/register"}, filterName = "regResponseFilter")
public class RegisterResponseFilter implements ResponseFilter{

@Override
@Context
public void ResponseFiltering(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {

     String origin = request.getHeader("Origin");

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","Post");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",origin);

}
```

Ошибки:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: coupon.filters.RegisterRequestFilter cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Filter
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5281)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

>java.lang.ClassCastException: coupon.filters.RegisterRequestFilter cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Filter
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5281)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html потому что `@WebFilter` по стандарту ставится только на реализации интерфейса Filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что нужно [имплементировать интерфейс](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html) `javax.servlet.Filter`, а у вас это просто класс.

Comment: А если я захотел своё написать и мне не нужно javax.servlet.Filter?

Comment: Значит будет `ClassCastException` :) Любой интерфейс - это контракт. JEE поволяет вам писать собственные фильтры, но для этого вы должны заключить контракт через реализацию интерфейса. Только так система сможет вам гарантировать правильную работу. Аннотация `@WebFilter` - не делает ваш класс фильтром, это просто пометка для контейнера сервлетов, чтобы он мог найти ваш класс в classpath.

Comment: Из твоего ответа это то что я понял что надо сделать и получил ту же ошибку. Как мне создать свой фильтр с классом и правильно реализовать его ?

Comment: Невнимательно читаете. Написано `имплементировать интерфейс javax.servlet.Filter`. А у вас какой-то `RequestFilter`.

Comment: Так я и написал с верху что не хочу его имплементировать.. 
Другого пути нет ? 
А если в web.xml настроить "Custom" фильтры к сервлетам?

Comment: Да, есть. Вы можете написать свой application server / контейнер сервлетов, по аналогии с Tomcat. Который не следует спецификации Servlet API, и не требует от фильтров реалмизации этого интерфейса.

Comment: Понятно)) Спасибо!